# Не работает position:fixed

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с тем что не работает `position: fixed`, перепробовал уже все, вот код в чем может быть проблема?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
      #header{
       position: fixed;
       width: 100%; 
       height: 10rem; 
       background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);  
       left: 0; 
       top: 0; 
       box-sizing: border-box; 
       padding: 0 5rem 0; 
       display: flex;
       justify-content: space-between;
       font-family: Sans-serif; 
      
      }
      .vertical_align_flex{
       align-self: center;
      }
      .link_menu{
       margin: 0 1.5rem 0; 
      }
      #wrap_menu a{
       text-decoration: none; 
       color: #197B30; 
       font-size: 2.4rem; 
       font-weight: 600; 
      }
      #wrap_menu a:hover{
       border-bottom: 0.2rem solid #197B30; 
      }
      #wrap_phone div{
       font-size: 2.6rem; 
       font-weight: 600;
      }
      #responsiveMenu{
       display: flex; 
       flex-wrap: wrap;
       transition: 0.5s max-height; 
       position: static;
      }
      .heightreqular{
       
      }
      #iconResponsiveMenu{
       display: none; 
      }
      .font_awesome{
       font-size: 4rem; 
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header id="header">
   <div id="wrap_logo" class="vertical_align_flex">
    <img src="image/logo.png">
   </div> 
   <div id="wrap_menu" class="vertical_align_flex">
    <div>
     <div id="iconResponsiveMenu">
      <em class="fa fa-bars font_awesome"></em>
     </div>
     <div id="responsiveMenu" class="heightreqular" >
      <div class="wraplink_mainMenu" >
       <a href="#main_page_photo" class="link_menu animatedLink">Главная</a>
      </div>
      <div class="wraplink_mainMenu">
       <a href="#product" class="link_menu animatedLink">Товары</a>
      </div> 
      <div class="wraplink_mainMenu"> 
       <a href="#about" class="link_menu animatedLink">О фирме</a>
      </div> 
      <div class="wraplink_mainMenu">
       <a href="#footer" class="link_menu animatedLink">Контактные данные</a>
      </div> 
     </div> 
    </div>
   </div> 
   <div id="wrap_phone" class="vertical_align_flex">
    <div>+ 7 (495) 909-09-09</div>
   </div>
  </header>
  </body>

</html>
```

P.S. Код вырван из контекста, работать так как надо не будет, но поверьте `position: fixed` не работает при всех тех стилях и тегах.

Comment: Может ваш `position:fixed;` чем-то перебивается? Смотрите в консоли (F12)

Comment: Я уже несколько раз обсмотрел css и html, ничего не заметил, может не знаю чего-то

Comment: И в каком именно месте не работает ваш `position:fixed`? У тега `header`?

Comment: Все работает, чего вы хотите конкретно добиться? непонятно

Comment: @Shillkas +1 к предыдущему комментарию. От себя предложу - добавьте `!important` и посмотрите, заработает или нет. Если заработает - значит где-то перебивается

Comment: да, у header не работает fixed

Comment: с !important тоже не работает

Comment: А, я разобрался, у body был position: relative с transform: translate, поэтому и не работало, вот я тупил, когда сюда вопрос залил сразу по другому начал мыслить